# I am trying to get my date and comment count to be included in the loop

Tags: php, loops

I am creating my first ever wordpress theme(and first time really using wordpress).

I am trying to get my date and comment count to be included in the loop even though I have it on the left in a sidebar and I can't figure out how to include it.

**Here is my code for the post (it includes the date, comment count, and post in that order with the post being part of the loop only currently) :**

(I am using the 960 grid so you may see grid classes below)

```
<div class="date_banner">
        <div class="d"><!-- sidebar 1 --><?php the_time('d'); ?></div>
        <div class="m"><!-- sidebar 1 --><?php the_time('M'); ?></div>
        <div class="y"><!-- sidebar 1 --><?php the_time('Y'); ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="commentsnumber">
    <?php comments_number('No comment', '1 comment', '% comments'); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_10">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <!-- post -->
        <div class="post">
            <div class="titlepostauthorimage">
            <div class="post-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="post-author-image">

            </div>
            <div class="post-author">
                 <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="post-image">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); ?> 
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post-bodyborder">
            <div class="post-body">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post-metaborder">
            <div class="post-meta">
                <?php the_category(', '); ?>
                <!-- post tags -->
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post-comments">
            <?php wp_list_comments( $args ); ?> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- post -->
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <!-- In case no posts were found -->
        <h1>Hmmm? Cam't. Find. Post.</h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

---

Here is what happens when I move the loop to above the date in the code in a test:[image: test]

the inspector says that in the first grid_10 class the date and comment count are below the post:
[image: inspector]

---

Here is what my finished theme is supposed to look like
and you can check out my work in progress at http://benlevywebdesign.com/wordpress/ (only the post is in the loop, the screen shots from above were a test/example of what happens when I just move the loop code)

[image: theme design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might goes something like this ( its just pseudocode )

```
<div class="container_16" >
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="grid_12" >
           <div class="grid_2"> date banner html goes in here </div>
           <div class="grid_10"> post html goes in here</div>          
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <!-- In case no posts were found -->
    <h1>Hmmm? Cam't. Find. Post.</h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Check it out now, I'm just having a small issue with the layout now

Comment: Now I just have my right side bar not being in the correct place issue

Comment: @benlevywebdesign It's best practice to open a new question for each issue. However, the problem seems to be with your grid. You are closing `grid_16` THEN including the sidebar instead of including the sidebar IN `grid_16` Add the sidebar to the top of the `grid_16` and float it right.

Answer (score 0):

To get post date and time use this

```
<?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>
```

To get comment count use this

```
 <?php comments_number('No reply', '1 reply', '% replies'); ?>
```

place anywhere in the loop

Ref:http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number

Comment: I already have the code for the date and comment count but I need to put in in the loop somehow with out changing my layout of my theme! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="grid_2">
    <div class="date_banner">
            <div class="d"><!-- sidebar 1 --><?php the_time('d'); ?></div>
            <div class="m"><!-- sidebar 1 --><?php the_time('M'); ?></div>
            <div class="y"><!-- sidebar 1 --><?php the_time('Y'); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="commentsnumber">
        <?php comments_number('No comment', '1 comment', '% comments'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- post -->
    <div class="grid_10 post">
        <div class="titlepostauthorimage">
            <div class="post-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="post-author-image">

            </div>
            <div class="post-author">
                 <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="post-image">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); ?> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="post-bodyborder">
            <div class="post-body">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="post-metaborder">
            <div class="post-meta">
                <?php the_category(', '); ?>
                <!-- post tags -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="post-comments">
        <?php wp_list_comments( $args ); ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- post -->
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <!-- In case no posts were found -->
    <h1>Hmmm? Cam't. Find. Post.</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Now I just need to fix the layout part